# PHP - Access Multidimension array element

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

So currently I am having some issues with trying to access an element in this multidimensional array. So what I am trying to do is to create 3 different arrays of different classes, and then return them in array at the end.

The problem comes when I am trying to accsess one of the array's in the $result array. I have checked and there are elements in the array's but I am unable to access them.

```
public function search($searchString) : array
{
        $bloggArr[] = array();
        $bloggerArr[] = array();
        $innleggArr[] = array();

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogg WHERE 
        bnavn=:bnavn");
        $stmt->bindParam('bnavn', $searchString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($blogg=$stmt->fetchObject("Blogg"))
        {
            $bloggArr[]=array('blogg'=>$blogg);
            echo $bloggArr['blogg']->hentBnavn();
            // sort($bloggArr);
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogger WHERE 
        fornavn=:fornavn OR etternavn=:etternavn");
        $stmt->bindParam('fornavn', $searchString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('etternavn', $searchString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($blogger = $stmt->fetchObject("Blogger"))
        {
            $bloggerArr[]= array('blogger' => $blogger);
            // sort($bloggArr);
        }

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM innlegg WHERE tittel=:tittel");
        $stmt->bindParam('tittel', $searchString, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        while ($innlegg = $stmt->fetchObject("Innlegg"))
        {
            $innleggArr[] = array('innlegg' => $innlegg);
            // sort($innleggArr);
        }
        $result = array('bloggArr' => $bloggArr, 'bloggerArr' => 
        $bloggerArr, 'innleggArr' => $innleggArr);
        return $result;
}
```

I thought I would be able to access the element in the second array by:

```
echo $resultat['bloggArr']['blogg']->SomeFunction();
```

the problem is that I get the error message that ['blogg'] is Undefined index. I am been unable to find a way to access the second array elements for a while now, and are wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Try to var_dump($resultat); and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using your arrays properly. Just considering `$bloggArr`:

```
$bloggArr[] = array();
```

creates this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

that line should be changed to:

```
$bloggArr = array();
```

To create an empty array. Then, each time through the loop,

```
$bloggArr[]=array('blogg'=>$blogg);
```

adds an element like this:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [blogg] => <your object>
    )
```

So, to access those values in the `$result` array you would need to use a loop:

```
foreach ($result['bloggArr'] as $blogg) {
    echo $blogg['blogg']->SomeFunction();
}
```

If your queries will only return one result, then you could simply change this line:

```
$bloggArr[]=array('blogg'=>$blogg);
```

to

```
$bloggArr=array('blogg'=>$blogg);
```

and then you could access the function via

```
echo $result['bloggArr']['blogg']->SomeFunction();
```